# How to convert JAXB annotated class to Schema instance at runtime?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I know about creating schemas at compile time (JAXB ) but how can i get this information at runtime .

Model class:

```
package pl.kkrzeminski;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Model {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    private String text;
}
```

How can i create at runtime instance of Schema based on JAXB metadata Model.java?

```
package pl.kkrzeminski;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException {
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        // TODO how can i create at runtime instance of Schema based on Model.java?
        javax.xml.validation.Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new Source[]{});
        schema.newValidator().validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream("<model><text>test</text></model>".getBytes())));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. What will be your input and expected output ?

Comment: validate input string with xml (json) at runtime, all classes are local, but there is now easy way to validate input, without full WebServices stack.

Comment: What's wrong with doing this at compile time? If there's a problem you can't fix it at runtime...

Comment: I try to use this schema for validating JSON input. I override MOXyJsonProvider i got everything to validate JSON except Schema.
Schema validation in webservices is too complex to extract for use in diffrent context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (nazgul-core-xmlbinding-spi-jaxb) found here:
[JAXB Validation Without Schema](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-430?focusedCommentId=366457&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-366457)

replace:

```
toReturn.setSystemId("");
```

with:

```
toReturn.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
```